# Will Celosia produce more than 1 flower head?

Tags: flowers

I may be asked to give some flowers to my church this year, so I'm wondering if Celosia argentea cristata can produce multiple flower heads in a season.

Comment: Celosia Asian Garden will: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Fbf%2F18%2Faa%2Fbf18aaceefff438507b9c26a586d223e.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com.au%2Fpin%2F273734483581062052%2F&docid=RykrQukYvgg6eM&tbnid=Cr-w--oE9rKn8M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjBsNLirvbaAhUM0lMKHbvhDq4QMwhlKCQwJA..i&w=800&h=800&itg=1&client=firefox-b-1&bih=725&biw=1554&q=celosia%20caterpillar&ved=0ahUKEwjBsNLirvbaAhUM0lMKHbvhDq4QMwhlKCQwJA&iact=mrc&uact=8  I'd make this an answer, but the links are all awful. Google 'celosia caterpiller' for lots of pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience they produced 3-5 small flower heads, but they grew closely together, so they could be harvested as one big flower head comprising all the small ones. If you mean to ask if that overcompassing flower head will be replaced by another one after it's cut, I don't know because I didn't cut it (I needed the seeds).

For multiple flower heads I would suggest Dahlia or another plant that becomes bushier after pinching it.